Transition on Fill property with linearGradient inside of SVG
I'm trying to achieve some kind of Stepper. It all works well except for the transition on the fill.


let step = 0;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
   step++;
   document.querySelector("svg").style.fill = `url(#lg-step-${step})`
})
.stepper {
    transition-property: fill;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
<svg id="test_svg" viewBox="0 0 620 50" width="300" height="20" fill="url(#lg-step-0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" class="stepper">
    <path d="m 71 29 h -60 c -14 0 -14 -19 0 -19 h 60 c 6 -10 19 -10 25 0 h 200 c 6 -10 19 -10 25 0 h 200 c 6 -10 19 -10 25 0 h 60 c 14 0 14 19 0 19 h -60 c -6 10 -19 10 -25 0 h -200 c -6 10 -19 10 -25 0 h -200 c -6 10 -19 10 -25 0" />
    <linearGradient id="lg-step-0">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="6%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="60%" />
        <stop offset="6%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="lg-step-1" >
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="14%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="60%"/>
        <stop offset="14%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="lg-step-2">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="60%" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="lg-step-3">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="87%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="60%" />
        <stop offset="87%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </linearGradient>

</svg>
<button> Next step </button>



All js here is not from my actual code but for testing purpose on SO.
I'd like to achieve some smooth transition between all my steps, but as you can see no transition is ever fired. Any help is appreciated.
Ps I'm actually working on Blazor so the less Js the better is the solution

I'm not an SME but I don't think you animate the fill you need to animate the gradient size/position.

SME ? But good idea, i'll try after lunch

Subject Matter Expert ☺ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850915/svg-animate-gradient-stop

@Symtox this might be helpful https://codepen.io/chirag0456/pen/KKjVdbR

transition can only interpolate between numbers of some sort, not between strings, and certainly not if those are references to complete DOM subtrees.
What you actually want to interpolate is the values of the offset attribute of the <stop> element. That is possible, but not with CSS. SVG has two sorts of attributes: those that are pure XML attributes, and "presentation attributes" where you can choose to write them as attributes or as CSS properties. Only the second are accessible by CSS transitions.
offset belongs to the first category. It can be animated, but only with a SMIL animation. The result is bulky, but it works.


let step = 0;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
   step++;
   document.querySelectorAll(`.lg-step-${step}`).forEach(el => {
      el.beginElement();
   })
})
<svg id="test_svg" viewBox="0 0 620 50" width="300" height="20" fill="url(#lg-step-0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" class="stepper">
    <path d="m 71 29 h -60 c -14 0 -14 -19 0 -19 h 60 c 6 -10 19 -10 25 0 h 200 c 6 -10 19 -10 25 0 h 200 c 6 -10 19 -10 25 0 h 60 c 14 0 14 19 0 19 h -60 c -6 10 -19 10 -25 0 h -200 c -6 10 -19 10 -25 0 h -200 c -6 10 -19 10 -25 0" />
    <linearGradient id="lg-step-0">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="6%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="60%">
            <animate class="lg-step-1" attributeName="offset" from=".06" to=".14"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
                     calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1" />
            <animate class="lg-step-2" attributeName="offset" from=".14" to=".5"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
                     calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1" />
            <animate class="lg-step-3" attributeName="offset" from=".5" to=".87"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
                     calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1" />
        </stop>
        <stop offset="6%" stop-color="transparent">
            <animate class="lg-step-1" attributeName="offset" from=".04" to=".14"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
                     calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1" />
            <animate class="lg-step-2" attributeName="offset" from=".14" to=".50"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
                     calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1" />
            <animate class="lg-step-3" attributeName="offset" from=".5" to=".87"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
                     calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1" />
        </stop>
    </linearGradient>
</svg>
<button> Next step </button>




When I click on Next Step  nothing happened, it's my machine or issue with code ?

Tested with Firefox 128 on Linux. Chromium 126 does not work, I see now. I have a hunch what that is, let me try...

I got disapointed when clicking the next button on chrome lmao. Works great on firefo,  huge thanks for the starting point !!

Works now. Chromium needs unitless values, percentages do not work (.14 instead of 14%). I wasn't aware of that bug.

You just made my day, thanks again

Btw, i' trying to "make it my own", but where does this begin comes from ? it is not even mentionned in MDN, do you have more reliable source for this topic (appart the 2k lines spec ?)

Here is the definition in the spec. Basically it says that the animation has no start point in the time line of the document. It needs to be triggered externally by a Javascript API call to AnimationElement.beginElement().

It's complex, but controling the timing is worth a read, because SMIL has more capabilities than CSS animations/transitions. Note though that wallclock-sync-value is not implemented by any browser.
